# SSD appears to shut down some time after boot only on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd

I've had this notebook for an year and it has worked normally until very recently.

I've got a dual boot system with Ubuntu 22.04(previously 20.04) and Windows 10.

On windows everything seems to work normally, but on any Linux systems(including an Arch bootable media) after 15-50 minutes all disk accesses fail with `Input/Output error` and eventually the system crashes.

I've ran S.M.A.R.T tests and they did not indicate any problems. I've also tried updating the firmware but there were no updates available.

The SSD is a WDC PC SN520.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If that also happens when you use a USB to boot your system, the problem is definitely not your SSD.